# Problem with definition of categorical variables in dismo package

Tags: r, maxent, dismo

I'm working with a package [dismo: Species Distribution Modeling](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dismo/index.html) and I have all my environmental variables as categorical. I used `"factors"` argument as follow:

```r
mod <- dismo::maxent(x = pder, 
                     p = pa,   
                     path = maxent_out,
                     args = c(...),
                     factors = c("first var name", "second var name"...)
                    )
```

The problem is that from the html file that I get, all my variables are considered as continuous. At this point I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: do you refer to the line among in last section in the maxent outcome whith says "Environmental layers used: altitude aspect dist_veg edaf(categorical) geolo(categorical) influenc_pop prec vegetation(categorical)". I just ran a maxent and cateroricals are printed like that

Comment: For me it says :" Environmental layers used (all continuous)" even I specified that all my variables are categorial in the argument "factors".